# Unable to install confluent Kafka (1.7.0) through poetry: not supporting PEP 517 builds

Tags: apache-kafka, python-poetry, confluent-kafka-python

So I am trying to pin confluent-kafka version to 1.7.0 to my poetry lock file. So in my toml file I would have:

confluent_kafka = "1.7.0"

But then when I run poetry update I get this error message:

```
at ~/.asdf/installs/poetry/1.4.0/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:152 in _prepare
      148│ 
      149│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      150│ 
      151│             if error is not None:
    → 152│                 raise error from None
      153│ 
      154│             return path
      155│ 
      156│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with confluent-kafka (1.7.0) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "confluent-kafka (==1.7.0)"'.
```

I'm not sure what I can do to correct this error. I am on a M1 Mac for reference.

Comment: There is an issue for this problem https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1357 If enough people upvote it, maybe it will be fixed.